# Exchange SAML access token for oauth token (Azure AD/Entra ID)

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory, saml, next-auth

I require an oauth token to make requests to a third party api on behalf of the user. Currently all users must login with SAML SSO using Azure AD. I am using boxyhq's saml-jackson with next-auth to facilitate this.

The saml access token does not allow for any authorisation to third party api's. I need to exchange it for a oauth token - I want this to occur without additional input from the user.

How can I implement an exchange with Azure AD to retrieve an oauth token using the access_token from boxyhq provider in next-auth?

I have looked at various resources but it is not clear to me. All thoughts are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to exchange a SAML 2.0 token to a OAuth/JWT access token with Azure AD/Entra ID.
You need to use some other exchange service.

It is possible to exchange a [SAML 2.0 token to a JWT access token](https://www.foxids.com/docs/token-exchange#saml-20-to-access-token-by-trust) with [FoxIDs.com](https://www.foxids.com/) using a free plan. You configur FoxIDs to trust Azure AD/Entra ID and FoxIDs can then based on the trust issue a JWT access token.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a 3rd-party API then you need an access token from that 3rd party. You should thus verify whether that vendor offers any features that will allow you to exchange one token for another. My guess, however, is that you will need some user interaction from the third party if they require user-bound access tokens to call their APIs.